# Unwanted backslashes in json response

Tags: python, json

I've wasted about 4 hours on different combinations of json.dumps, json.loads, etc... trying to figure this out to no avail.  It appears my sting is being double serialized, but I have no idea how or why.  Need some help.  I get the following output from my API call:

```
{"error": "message\": \"Invalid parameter options - \"to\" must be later than \"from\"."}
```

I do NOT want these backslashes in the response.

Code snippet below:

```
err_msg = 'message": "Invalid parameter options - "to" must be later than "from".'
        
if err_msg != '':
    #Some error has occurred.  Send it back in the response.
    result = {}
    result['error'] = err_msg

    responseObject = {}
    responseObject['statusCode'] = 400
    responseObject['headers'] = {}
    responseObject['headers']['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    responseObject['body'] = json.dumps(result)
    return responseObject
```

Comment: Literal doublequotes in JSON have to be escaped.

Comment: Don't worry about it. When you later parse the JSON, the backslashes will be removed.

Comment: What do you want `err_msg` to be? Right now, its a single string with interior double quotes. JSON escapes those quotes for its protocol but a deserializer would get rid of them again.

Comment: The backslashes are integeral to JSON - it uses double quotes for its own purposes and needs to escape yours. If you don't like the escapes, don't use the double qoutes. You could for instance use single quotes - `"message: 'whatever'"`.

Comment: But really, why does it matter? Its serialized data - its gonna bit a bit messy  but your computer doesn't care.

Answer (score 0):

JSON uses double quote `"` in its protocol so it has to escape double quotes found inside strings to avoid confusion. The serialized JSON has escapes... but who cares? That's just computer to computer stuff. Deserialize and it will all look correct again.

The original string

```
>>> import json
>>> err_msg = 'message": "Invalid parameter options - "to" must be later than "from".'
>>> print(err_msg)
message": "Invalid parameter options - "to" must be later than "from".
```

serialized

```
>>> serialized = json.dumps(err_msg)
>>> print(serialized)
"message\": \"Invalid parameter options - \"to\" must be later than \"from\"."
```

deserialized

```
>>> deserialized = json.loads(serialized)
>>> print(deserialized)
message": "Invalid parameter options - "to" must be later than "from".
```

and its the same stuff

```
>>> deserialized == err_msg
True
```

Answer (score -1):

You have unwanted backslashes because the double-quotes need to be escaped (In JSON).

You could change `err_msg` to something like:

`err_msg = "message": "Invalid parameter options - 'to' must be later than 'from'."`

(Sorry if I got something wrong, I don't really use the JSON library in Python much and I don't really use JSON)